# cakephp work with xml

Tags: cakephp

how work with xml class in cakePHP 1.3?

I have this code:

```
function xml_test()
{

 echo $this->Xml->header(array('version'=>'1.1'));
 echo $this->Xml->serialize($data, array('format' => 'tags');
}
```

and get error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'header' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

Why, whats wrong?

```
Query: header
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you haven't included the Xml helper in your controller, e.g.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
.
.
    var $helpers = array('Xml');
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a SQL query somehow connected to the value "header" anywhere else but not in your example code which breaks the SQL syntax.

Search for "header" or check if any parameter is set to "header".